# Why am I not able to initialize git in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I have created a react app to host on my github page. I am aware of the hosting procedure involved in that but I am not able to initialize git for my app. 
Has somebody faced this before or if anyone can help me out understanding this, I would be thankful. Please find the screenshot of the same:

[image]

```
 git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ git init
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: The error clearly says: "git is not recognized as a cmdlet". This is not a problem with react or github. It seems like you don't have git installed

Comment: thanks for fast response. that's the problem patrick, git is installed on my system but still getting this error.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Apology. I thought it would be very common issue and by just looking at the image someone can place it in their logic. anyway i have added error as text in question.

Comment: How about trying to install git from https://git-scm.com/download/win?

Answer (score 0):

If [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) is installed, you can try the same git init from a regular CMD instead of a PowerShell session.

That way, you validate that Git itself works, and then can debug the Powershell issue.